# Record are multiple recorded on DB after jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have problem
I'm validating text field (click submit button) and if value is true then i need to use jQuery dialog to get another permissions (enter another code). But if user closing down the dialog box and click submit button again then dialog box come up again (this is good) user entering code in to dialog form and submitting. Then i have two records (duplicated) on my database. If user closing-submitting dialog box 3 times then i have 3 dublicated records:

```
$('#f_button').click(function(){

// validation

{

// if true
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
$("#test_button").click(function() {

    $.ajax({                 // validating text field in dialog
        type: 'POST',
        url: file.php',

        data: $('#form_name).serialize(),
        success: function validate(data1) {
            if (data1 == 1) {

                $("#text_field").css('background-color', '#00FF00');
                $('#another_form')[0].submit();

} else {    
                $("#text_field").css('background-color', '#FF0000');

                            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: It's because you're submitting your ajax every time they click the button, so if you show them the box 3 times and they click the button 3 times you'll get three records.

Comment: @Styphon No. If whey clicking 3 times then fine because is different records. but problem is if users closing X dialog then I have dublicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set ajax post request after completing of all of your validations 
do not put it to on submit button put it to dialog box conformation button so you post request not gone and you can easily handle that